# 401(woocommerce_api_user_cannot_read_product) response--Woocommerce REST API

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

the API works when ck_ and cs_ keys are for Admin and returns the std class object but when keys are for a different user returns You do not have permission to read this product 401(woocommerce_api_user_cannot_read_product) Error response: even when user has read/write privileges. but goes ahead to create the product in the database. Any help on this issue is highly appreciated

require_once( 'lib/woocommerce-api.php' );

```
$options = array(
    'debug'           => true,
    'return_as_array' => false,
    'validate_url'    => false,
    'timeout'         => 30,
    'ssl_verify'      => false,
);
try {
$client = new WC_API_Client( $the_url, 'ck_xxxx', 'cs_xxxx', $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding into your `$options` array:

```
$options['query_string_auth'] = true;
```

As noted in the documentation this will "Force Basic Authentication as query string true" in other words it will append your consumer key and consumer secret to your request URL as a query string.  This is only supported on HTTPS.